# How can I create multiple columns in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working in aws cluster with r5.8xlarge instances, with python3.7, apache-spark-3.2 to create multiple columns.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

columns = ['id', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']
data = [['0000', None, None, None, 0],
        ['0001',   10,    2, 10.1, 0],
        ['0002',   20, None, 20.1, 0],
        ['0003',   30,    2, 30.1, 0]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)


col_dict = {"new_col_1": {"minuend": F.col("col_1"),
                          "subtrahend": F.col("col_2")},
            "new_col_3": {"minuend": F.col("col_1"),
                          "subtrahend": F.col("col_3")},
            "new_col_4": {"minuend": F.col("col_1"),
                          "subtrahend": F.col("col_4")},
            "new_col_5": {"minuend": F.col("col_2"),
                          "subtrahend": F.col("col_1")},
            }

for col, metadata in col_dict.items():
    df = df.withColumn(col, (F.when(metadata["minuend"].isNull(), F.lit(None))
                             .when(metadata["subtrahend"].isNull(), F.lit(None))
                             .otherwise(metadata["minuend"] - metadata["subtrahend"])
                             ).cast(T.DoubleType())
                       )
df.checkpoint()
```

The above was a example, in the real case the df dataframe has 2 million rows and 1k columns, and the col_dict dictionary has 10k keys (I want to create 10k new columns).
The failure does not occur when the next action is executed (the checkpoint). It occurs in the for loop when the withColumns are performed, the loop never ends and the driver kills all executors.

I think the cause of the error is that an excessively large DAG is generated.

Can anyone help me?

This error didn't happen with spark 2.4 version, so I think it must be solved by setting some spark tuning configuration.

I have tried to increase the driver memory, overhead memory and off heap memory, but I am not able to solve the error.

Comment: Did you tried generating all those columns in a `select`? This article explains the hidden cost of `withColumn`, it can help in your use case: https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015

Comment: every single `withColumn` creates a new projection in the spark plan. in your case, you generate 10k projections of the same data, each with a new column. the 10k projections will create a huge overhead and run out of memory. you can create multiple columns in a `select` which will create only 1 projection.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to create the sample data.

```
#
# 1 - create data for the problem
#

# include libraries
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# array of columns
cols = ['id', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']

# array of data
dats = [['0000', None, None, None, 0],
        ['0001',   10,    2, 10.1, 0],
        ['0002',   20, None, 20.1, 0],
        ['0003',   30,    2, 30.1, 0]]

# create dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(dats, cols)

# create view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_dataset")
```

As far as I know (AFAIK), None is used to insert a null value into a dataframe.  We do not need to worry about that in Spark SQL since it will return null if any of the columns in the subtraction are null.

%sql

```
--
-- 2 - create new columns (substraction)
--

select 
  t.*,
  t.col_1 - t.col_2 as new_col_2,
  t.col_1 - t.col_3 as new_col_3,
  t.col_1 - t.col_4 as new_col_4,
  t.col_2 - t.col_1 as new_col_5
from tmp_dataset as t
```

You can use df2.sql() on the statement above to create a dataframe.  I just ran it in using the SQL magic cmd.  The image below shows the output.

[image]